# Convert a you tube downloaded video to MOV format in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, youtube, mov

I'm developing an iOS app, which needs to convert a video downloaded using you tube APIs into .mov format. I've tried using AVExportSession output file type set to .mov.`

```
    NSURL * mediaURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputURL];
    AVAsset *video = [AVAsset assetWithURL:mediaURL];
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:video presetName:AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080];
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
    documentsPath=[documentsPath stringByAppendingString:@"/Youtube"];
    BOOL isDir;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsPath isDirectory:&isDir]) {
        NSError *createDirError;
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:documentsPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&createDirError]) {
            if (createDirError) {
                NSLog(@"eror while creating dir == %@", createDirError);
            }
        }
    }
    documentsPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.mov",arc4random()%10000]];

    exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentsPath];

    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        switch (exportSession.status) {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
            {
                ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
                [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputURL] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"error>%@",error.description);
                    }
                    else{
                        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputURL])
                        {
                            [[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtPath:outputURL error:nil];
                        }
                        NSLog(@"asseturl>%@",assetURL);
                        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputURL error:nil];
                        [self addAssetURL:assetURL toAlbum:@"Fame" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                            if(error)
                            {
                                NSLog(@"Error in saving to Fame album : %@",error.description);
                                return;
                            }
                        }];
                    }
                }];
            }
                break;

            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                NSLog(@"Error : %@",exportSession.error.description);

            default:
                break;
        }
        NSLog(@"done processing video!");
    }];
```

`

This code saves the video to gallery, but when I fetch the video using asset library, I get mp4 in the url.

Comment: [`MOV`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.mov) is container format just like [`MP4`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.mp4). MP4 is based on MOV. So what kind of encoding do you want?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I haven't done any kind of encoding on video explicitly and have no idea if the AVExportSession does any kind of encoding implicitly. So I'm unaware about the encoding used. Please suggest the best way to convert mp4 video to mov format.